# Sum of elements of higher power of matrix $ A $, when sum of elements in each row of $ A $ is $ 1 $

Tags: matrices, determinant, exponentiation

Let $ A $ be a $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix such that the sum of elements in each row is $ 1 $. Find out the sum of all the elements in $ A ^ { 10 } $.

I don't know anything about how to get a connection between the two statements without actually calculating $ A ^ { 10 } $, which will not be an efficient process.

Also, I don't know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors which were used in some questions I saw for determining the relationship between $ A $ and $ A ^ { - 1 } $. I don't think the inverse calculation is useful in this question.

What should be understood to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** Before we see what happens in $A^{10}$, let's explore $A^2$.

So let $A = (a_{ik})_{i,k=1}^n$ with $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} = 1$ for all $i \in [n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

Note that if $A^2 = (b_{ik})_{i,k=1}^n$ then
$$
b_{ik} = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} a_{jk}
$$
and the sum of one row would be
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ik}
 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} a_{jk}
 = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{jk} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\right)
 = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{jk} \cdot 1
 = 1.
$$
Can you follow this logic to see what happens in $A^{10}$?

---

**UPDATE** Your supposition that every row of $A^k$ will sum to $1$ for all positive integers $k$ is correct. One way to convince yourself of that is that every stochastic matrix (one where each row sums to $1$) can be seen as a transition matrix of a Markov Chain with states $[n]$. Then, $A^2$ is the matrix of 2-step transitions, and $A^k$ is the matrix of $k$-step transitions, both of which must be stochastic as well...

Comment: It is coming out the same for $A^{10}$, so it means that sum of one row will be 1 and the sum of all the elements will be 4. Am I right?

Comment: @DivyanshVerma correct, see the update